# Android audio track change pitch but not speed

Tags: android, audio

Hi guys I'm trying to change the pitch of the sound when it is played.

I'm using Audio Track.

```
public void start() {
    if (isPlaying()) {
        return;
    }
    mKeepPlaying = true;
    mAudioTrack.flush();
    if(mAudioTrack != null)
    {
        mAudioTrack.setPlaybackRate(44100);
        mAudioTrack.play();
        // Setting thread feeding the audio samples to the audio hardware.
        // (Assumes mChannels = 1 or 2).
        mPlayThread = new Thread()
        {
            public void run() {
                int position = mPlaybackStart * mChannels;
                mSamples.position(position);
                int limit = mNumSamples * mChannels;
                while (mSamples.position() < limit && mKeepPlaying)
                {
                    int numSamplesLeft = limit - mSamples.position();
                    if (numSamplesLeft >= mBuffer.length)
                    {
                        mSamples.get(mBuffer);
                    } else
                    {
                        for (int i = numSamplesLeft; i < mBuffer.length; i++)
                        {
                            mBuffer[i] = 0;
                        }
                        mSamples.get(mBuffer, 0, numSamplesLeft);
                    }
                    // TODO(nfaralli): use the write method that takes a ByteBuffer as argument.
                    mAudioTrack.write(mBuffer, 0, mBuffer.length);


                }
            }
        };

    mPlayThread.start();
    }
}
```

So if I change the setPlayBackRate() to 88200, the pitch increases but the speed of the sound increases. How do I make it play at the same speed as 44100?

The app I saw on Google Play, Music Speed Changer is exactly what I want. I want to be able to change the Pitch Octaves +1.00 or -1.00 without the speed of the audio changing

Comment: You need a phase vocoder.

Comment: Do you have any guide/tutorials or codes?

Comment: I understand the basics of how they work but that is well beyond the scope of this question. I'd recommend you search for a library.